# combinatorics To prove: $\binom{n}0\binom{n}1 + \binom{n}1\binom{n}2 + \dots + \binom{n}{n-1}\binom{n}n=\frac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!(n+1)!}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

To prove:
$$\binom{n}0\binom{n}1 + \binom{n}1\binom{n}2 + \dots + \binom{n}{n-1}\binom{n}n=\frac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!(n+1)!}$$

Have no idea about how to do it. Related to Binomial coefficient.

Comment: Would you get this question if say $n=1$ or $n=2$? Can you attempt mathematical induction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Rewrite the left side as:

$$\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{n-2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n-1}\binom{n}{0}$$

Rewrite the right side as:

$$\binom{2n}{n-1}$$